# VueJs do a reload on a simple table from Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

So I have a vuetify simple table that displays available times to book appointments.  However, this times are pull from a database and that information get changes every 5 minutes (based on people that booked or cancel).  The user will need to refresh the table to get the latest changes.   Im trying to introduce some sort of auto refresh in VueJs that reloads the data every 5 minuts.   this is my method that is been called right now

```
created(){
    this.fetchAvailableTimeSlotsData75();

  },


    method:{

  fetchAvailableTimeSlotsData75() {
     this.$axios.get('appointments75', {
            params: {
              date: this.isCurrentMonth(this.strSelectedDate) ? '' : this.strSelectedDate,
              week: this.intPageNumber
            }
          })
            .then((objResponse) => {
              if(objResponse.status == 200){
                // console.log(objResponse.data)
                this.total = objResponse.data.total;
                this.arrAvailableDates    = objResponse.data.dates;
                this.arrAppointmentsData  = objResponse.data.data;
                this.getAppointments();
              }
            })
            .catch((objError) => {
              
            })
            .finally(() => {
              this.blnLoading = false;
              this.snackbar = false
            });}
}
```

Whats the best way to approach this in VueJs?   Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply, use `setInterval`:

```js
var _timerId;

export default {
  data: () => ({
    pollingInterval: 1000 * 60 * 5
  }),

  created() {
    this.startPolling(true);
  },

  methods: {
    startPolling(init = false) {
      if (init) {
        // Call it immediately
        this.fetchAvailableTimeSlotsData75();
        this.startPolling();
        return;
      }

      _timerId = setInterval(this.fetchAvailableTimeSlotsData75, this.pollingInterval);
    }
  },

  // Optional
  destroyed() {
    clearInterval(_timerId);
  }
}
```